How to compare two rows for variable data, using a formula
My table is as follows (although this is a sample, the actual table is 12Rx20C):



Order
Markers
Markers
Markers
Result




50K
Marker A
0
0
NEG


50K
Marker A
0
0
NEG


601
Marker A
Marker B
0
NEG


95Y
Marker B
Marker C
0
POS


95Y
Marker B
Marker C
0
NEG


M22
Marker F
0
0
POS


M22
Marker F
0
0
NEG


K3S
Marker F
0
0
NEG


K3S
Marker F
0
0
NEG


K12
0
0
0
POS


K12
0
0
0
NEG



0
0
0




0
0
0




0
0
0




On the worksheet, there's also a list of all makers (named list MARKERLIST):



Marker list




Marker A


Marker B


Marker C


Marker D


Marker E


Marker F


Marker G


Marker H


Marker I



Both the order column and Markers columns are filled by a formula.
I'm trying to come up with a formula that fills in the 'Result' column. The following rules should apply:

Adding a marker is not a problem, so NEG (so 50K to 601, marker B is added);
When a marker is replaced, or dropped, that's a POS (601 to 97Y, marker A is swapped for marker C/ K3S to K12, marker F is dropped);
Changing from one set of markers to another is a POS (95Y to M22 is a different set);
Changing order, but keeping markers, is a NEG (M22 to K3S);

So far I've tried a COUNTIFs: =TRANSPOSE(COUNTIFS(B2:B4 , MARKERLIST) for all rows.
Then applying a MAP function between two rows to find differences, along the lines of =MAP(COUNTIFS row 1, COUNTIFS row2, LAMBDA(a, b, IF(a>=b, 0, 1); which is then summed.
But this method gives a lot of false results, especially when a marker(set) appears multiple times in a row.
I tried to add in a SCAN function of the order list, to detect changes over there (one order always has the same marker set), but this still doesn't completely fix it. =SCAN(0, Ordercolumn, LAMBDA(a, b, IF(b = OFFSET(b, 1, 0), 1, "")
Preferably it would be done in a single column, but helper columns are allowed, although I'd like to keep them to a minimal.

I hope this makes sense, if anything is unclear, let me know and I'll try to edit in a better explanation.

I think you are looking for something like this?
Formula in F3 is below and can be filled down:
=IF(AND((ISNUMBER(XMATCH(B2:D2,B3:D3,0,1))+(B2:D2=0))>0),"NEG","POS")
ISNUMBER(XMATCH(B2:D2,B3:D3,0,1))+(B2:D2=0) checks whether each marker in row2 is either in row3, or is 0.
If all markers in row2 is available in row3 or is just 0, then row3 is NEG, otherwise POS.


As far as I can test it, it seems to work great!

Just matching, I mean mapping rachel's nice answer, as a dynamic formula (without need to fill down); assuming if an order has same markers, they will be in same position - please let me know if it is not the case.
Updated 2024-08-02
=LET(markers, B2:D15, orders, A2:A15, MAP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(markers)), LAMBDA(i, IFS(
AND(ISBLANK(INDEX(orders, i)), i > 1, OR(INDEX(markers, i - 1,0) <> 0)), "POS",
ISBLANK(INDEX(orders, i)), "", 
i = 1, "NEG",
AND((INDEX(markers, i - 1, 0) = 0) 
+ (INDEX(markers, i, 0) = INDEX(markers, i - 1, 0))), "NEG",
TRUE, "POS"))))

Mark POS after last order with markers

With empty order as last order


Neat! Thanks for your answer. One thing (which I think i didn't mention), after the last order with a marker is done, there should also be a 'POS'. While that works in your example, because there's an empty order (K12), it doesn't seem to do that when the last order in the list has markers. Like if K3s were the last order, the next result row should be 'POS' (and the rest 'NEG' or empty). Markers are always picked from the list down, and each order always has the same markers, so their order is always the same as well.

@Excellor, thanks for testing it! I've updated the formula - please test it when you have time. I hope I have understood the requirement correctly.

works like a charm! Thanks for your update, I'll test some with both and see what works best in the actual file.

just found out one more thing, the list might start with 'empty' orders, but if there's an order with a marker after that, it will also flag it as 'POS'.  Although I fixed it, by adjusting the formula that takes in the markers from the list. (It's a FILTER function, and the 'not found' part was filled with "", changed that to 0, now it works just fine.)

Glad to hear it - thanks for your feedback.
